# Get Change Function of DropDownList While Using Tuple for Multiple Models

Tags: jquery, razor, model-view-controller

I am using [this idea](https://forums.asp.net/t/2086795.aspx?How%20people%20use%20Tuple%20in%20MVC) to use 2 models in the same View. As I change my single model to a multiple model, I also had to change:

- from: model.VendorId
- to: model.Item1.VendorId

For example,

Original:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VendorId, "Vendor")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VendorId, ViewBag.VendorName as SelectList, "--Select Vendor--", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

After adding "Item1":

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item1.VendorId, "Vendor")
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Item1.VendorId, ViewBag.VendorName as SelectList, "--Select Vendor--", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
```

All the changes worked fine. However, one of my cascade dropdown jquery function, which is triggered by a change in the dropdown, stopped working.

The way that I used to trigger this function was:

```
<script>
        //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
         $("#VendorId").change(function ()
         {
```

After adding Item1, this function is not being triggered.Then, I tried, without success, to change to this:

```
<script>
        //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
         $("#Item1.VendorId").change(function ()
         {
```

As mentioned, this function is not being called as before even though I change "#VendorId" to "Item1.VendorId". How should I call this change function if I am using @model Tuple< and Item1.

Extra information:
One of my ideas was to change the way that I call my Change function. However, the reason why I did not pursue this solution is that most of my cascade dropdown (using DropDownListFor) is built on the idea of calling the dropdownlistfor as ""#IndexFamilyID"":

```
<script>
        //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
         $("#VendorId").change(function ()
         {

            console.log('1HereStart');

            $("#IndexFamilyID").empty();

            $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("SelectFamilies")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#VendorId").val() },
                success: function (families)
                {
                    $.each(families, function (i, family)
                    {

                        $("#IndexFamilyID").append('<option value="'
                            + family.indexFamilyID + '">'
                            + family.indexFamilyName + '</option>');
                });
            },
                error: function (ex)
                {
                alert('Failed to retrieve families.' + ex.responseText);
            }
            });

            console.log('1HereEnd');

        return false;
        });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you please render the actual HTML code when the page is invoked please?

Answer (score 0):

Following the idea in one of the comments, I checked, using the Insperctor from the browser, in how the names were being created.

For the call a .change function I should do like this:

What I wrongly have tried:

```
<script>
    $("#Item1.VendorId").change(function () {
        console.log('Blabla1');
    });
</script>
```

What it worked for me:

```
<script>
    $("#Item1_VendorId").change(function () {
        console.log('Blabla1');
    });
</script>
```

Notice that I used "." when I should be using "_"